# ajax ReRender throws away the html tags for inputs that it re-renders

Tags: jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

First of all I am  new to AJAX and JSF so excuse my ignorance. 
I am troubleshooting an issue on one of our existing applications. 
Basically we want to rerender certain input fields if another has a value in it. 
The code looks as follows

```
<rich:column  valign="top" align="center">

    <f:facet name="header">QTY Locos   <br/>Staged</f:facet>
    <h:inputText id="qtyLocos" value="#{dataItem.qtyLocosStaged}" width="80px" disabled="#{dataItem.rejected or !stagingDetailBean.editable}" styleClass="inputValidNumber">
         <rich:jQuery selector="#qtyLocos" timing="onload" query="numeric" />
         <a4j:support event="onchange" limitToList="true" reRender="facesMessagePanel, locoType, teleRequired, crewQualification" />
    </h:inputText>
</rich:column>
<rich:column  valign="top" styleClass="inputValid" id="locoType" align="center">
    <f:facet name="header">Loco Type</f:facet>
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{dataItem.locoType}"   disabled="#{dataItem.qtyLocosStaged eq 0 or dataItem.rejected or !stagingDetailBean.editable}">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="6E" itemLabel="6E" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="6E1" itemLabel="6E1" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="7E" itemLabel="7E" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</rich:column>
<rich:column valign="top" styleClass="center" id="teleRequired">
    <f:facet name="header">Telemeter<br/>Required</f:facet>
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{dataItem.telemeterRequired}"  disabled="#{dataItem.qtyLocosStaged eq 0 or dataItem.rejected or !stagingDetailBean.editable}"/>
</rich:column>
```

On certain browsers when you enter a value in the input field id=qtyLocos the drop down list and tick box becomes active as the criteria for disabled is now false. 
But it happens in certain browsers that when you enter a value and the onchange event kicks in it physically removes the HTML tags for the drop down and the tick box. So my page renders completely incorrect.

Is anyone aware of issues with certain versions of chrome and ajax that could explain this behavior?

Some more info regarding this issue. The column headers dont disappear they are still visable. Just the inputs are missing, shifting all the fields after these fields to the left (and then not aligning with its column name anymore)

Ok this problem is getting weirder by the moment. This ONLY happens on machines that are on the company domain. Any machine that doesnt log onto the domain this does not happen. Can company policies influence how these things gets rendered?

Comment: Is that possible that your browsers in company domain disallow javascript code execution?

Comment: @robson Hi. No because other javascripts work. Also this problem is intermittent sometimes works  and sometimes doesnt. So not sure what is going here...

Comment: Did you look in JS console for any JS errors?

Comment: @BalusC yes, there are no errors.. I am looking at other issues now, hopefully if i come back to this problem with fresh eyes i will see the problem...